# Migrate Dead Active Directory Domain Controller from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 acted as Active Directory Domain Controller.

Last week it suddenly stopped working. There are no working backups and there are no other DC.

When I check the server, the AD and DNS services are not running, and I can't make it work no matter what I tried.

Is there any way I can get my AD to other server?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it's technically possible to copy the AD database files off the non-working DC and seed a new DC with them during the promotion process, but you're definitely going to be fighting an uphill battle.

You'd be better off to call MS Support, assuming that fixing this properly is worth approx $250. Assuming you've done the basics, which you have not described. Have you tried Directory Services Restore Mode?

And start taking backups, and always run two DCs per domain in the future.